# Repopulate _schemas Topic from cache

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

A few days ago we lost all data on our kafka brokers, so also all messages in the internal `_schemas` topic used by schema registry.

The schema registry nodes are still up and running though, so we still have all schemas in the cache. My Question is:
How can I repopulate the `_schemas` topic with the schemas from the cache? Or is that even the right approach here?

Comment: How does that even happen? Did you forget to change the default log directory away from /tmp?

Answer (score 0):

Not directly, no. In fact, I'd be surprised if the registry server was still running if the brokers it used were down.

You can spin up an empty registry, then loop over `GET /subjects` of the old one, for each version, then `POST` to the new one.

It won't be perfect since that'll miss any deleted schemas, but it's the best you can do with the data available